# Adding rows / columns to existing matrices in core.matrix (Clojure)

Tags: matrix, clojure

How does one add a row or a column to an existing matrix? I'm trying to add a bias-term, a column of ones, as the first row of a matrix. In Octave I can do this with:

```
M = [ones(size(M, 1), 1), M];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `join` function to append arrays along the major dimension.

And you can combine this with `broadcast` to get a matrix of ones in whatever size you like, e.g.:

e.g.

```
(join (broadcast 1 [1 3]) 
      [[1 2 3] 
       [4 5 6]   
       [7 8 9]])
=> [[1 1 1] 
    [1 2 3] 
    [4 5 6] 
    [7 8 9]]
```

Comment: That was fast! So to add a bias-term I could do something like:

`(->> M transpose (join (broadcast 1 [1 (first (shape M))])) transpose)`

yeah? Or is there an even better way of accomplishing the same?

Comment: @Olli - There will be a `join-along` function in an upcoming `core.matrix` release which will avoid the need for the transposes by allowing you to join on any dimension. But currently I think your code is probably the simplest way to do it.